# Jquery loader not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following... http://jsfiddle.net/yUVF4/3/ Basically it's just a form which when the button is pressed a loading screen should appear using the javascript there and the resource I've added `jquery.loader.js`. However, It's not working and I can't seem to grasp why. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Is it working if you try the code outside jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `div` wrapper in the content parameter of the plugin, it works

```
content:'<div>Loading...</div>'
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/yUVF4/11/)